# Can one make monetized video content playing a game that includes a modification licensed under CC BY-NC-ND 4.0

Tags: licensing

There is a [modification](https://mods.factorio.com/mod/IndustrialRevolution) to a game [Factorio](https://www.factorio.com/) that adds content and changes the gameplay. It is licensed under [CC BY-NC-ND 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/), and the [author claims](https://mods.factorio.com/mod/IndustrialRevolution/faq) it is therefore forbidden to create monetized content of the game with this modification (for example streaming on twitch or youtube). The FAQ reads:

> > Can I stream or showcase this mod on Twitch / YouTube / social media?
>
> Yes, as long as you are not doing it to generate any income. The
> license prohibits any use of this mod for any commercial purpose.
> Monetised streaming is very obviously a commercial purpose. No
> exceptions.

There are many other modifications under this license, but only this one is made with this clarification, and it's only this one modification that people fear making content with. Many content creators would like to know whether there's legal ground to the statement above, in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

### No, you cannot monitize your video content

The NC part of the license prohibits commercialization, that is, making money from it. The FAQ is correct.